# Update time only

Tags: java, datetime

Is there any way to update only a Date's time path?
I tried `Date.setTime()` but it replaces the date path too. I there any java method or the only way is to set hour, minute, second and milisecond?

Thank you

Comment: I don't have the methods handy, but I suggest storing the date object and start altering from there.

Comment: what do you mean by _Date's time path_ and _Date's date path_?

Comment: @ATaylor I can't store date and time in the same field because the date can be empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Java `Date` is just a wrapper around a `long` that counts time from the epoch (January 1, 1970). Much more flexible is [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). You can create a `Calendar` from a `Date`:

```
Date date = . . .;
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Then you can set various fields of the `Calendar`:

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
// etc.
```

Comment: cal.setDate(date); is undefined. only cal.setTime(date) is available.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar - Oops. Thanks for catching that. Now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by moving away from `java.util.Date` entirely. Ideally, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as it's a *far* more capable date/time library.

Otherwise, you should use `java.util.Calendar`. A `java.util.Date` doesn't *have* a particular date/time until you decide what time zone you're interested in - it just represents an *instant* in time, which different people around the world will consider to be a different date and time of day.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take a look at [java.util.Calender](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

It will allow you to change the individual parts of the date/time.

```
Calendar cal = Calender.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calender.HOUR, hour);
```

Alternatively, as has already being suggested, I'd take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)